# Login Logout Session in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, logout

I am trying to implement Login Logout functionality for my project website. I'm making SPA. what is the best way to make login/logout global i.e. if I click on any other link like contact us or about us after logging in logout remains till clicked? Where I'm going wrong How to correct it? 
What logic shall I apply so that logout remains till the end?
I have used javascript to change login button to logout

What I want to know is how do I get a login/logout button to display across the entire portal and our unauthenticated site based on if the user is logged in or out? Is it possible for me to execute my code on the header somehow? Or do you have any other suggestions? Currently when I click on signin button then value of temp is passed true and logout button is displayed but now when I click on any other page like about us value of temp hasn't been passed true ..so how to do this across complete portal?

**UserController.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView loginHere() {
        log.debug("Starting of the method loginHere");
        System.out.println("loginHere");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/home");
        mv.addObject("user", user);
        mv.addObject("isUserClickedLoginHere", "true");
        mv.addObject("message", "Welcome to login page");
        log.debug("Ending of the method loginHere");
        System.out.println("Ending login here");

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView validate(@RequestParam(value = "username") String userID,
            @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {
        log.debug("Starting of the method validate");
        System.out.println("validate");

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/home");

        user = userDAO.validate(userID, password);
        // if the record exist with this userID and password it will return user
        // details else will return null
        if (user != null) {
            log.debug("Valid Credentials");

            session = req.getSession();  
/*          session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1*10);
*/          

            session.setAttribute("loggedInUser", user.getName());
            session.setAttribute("loggedInUserID", user.getUsername());

            session.setAttribute("user", user);

            mv.addObject("homePagee", "true");
            mv.addObject("temp", "true");

            if (user.getRole().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                log.debug("Logged in as Admin");
                mv.addObject("isAdmin", "true");
                /*
                 * session.setAttribute("supplier", supplier);
                 * session.setAttribute("supplierList", supplierDAO.list());
                 * 
                 * session.setAttribute("category", category);
                 * session.setAttribute("categoryList", categoryDAO.list());
                 */

            } else {
                log.debug("Logged in as User");
                mv.addObject("isAdmin", "false");

                // myCart = cartDAO.list(userID);
                /*
                 * mv.addObject("myCart", myCart); // Fetch the myCart list
                 * based on user ID List<MyCart> cartList =
                 * cartDAO.list(userID); mv.addObject("cartList", cartList);
                 * mv.addObject("cartSize", cartList.size());
                 */
            }

        } else {
            log.debug("Invalid Credentials");

            mv.addObject("invalidCredentials", "true");
            mv.addObject("errorMessage", "Invalid Credentials");

        }
        log.debug("Ending of the method validate");
        return mv;
    }

@RequestMapping("/logout")
public ModelAndView logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    log.debug("Starting of the method logout");
    System.out.println("Starting of the method logout");

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/home");
    session.invalidate();
    session = request.getSession(true);
    mv.addObject("homePagee", "true");
    mv.addObject("temp1", "true");

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (auth != null) {
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    System.out.println("Ending of the method logout");

    log.debug("Ending of the method logout");
    return mv;
    // return "redirect:/login?logout";

}
```

**Logout.JSP**

```
<c:if test="${temp}">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /* var loginbtn =  document.getElementById("login-btn");
            var signupbtn = document.getElementById("signup-btn");
            var myaccountbtn = document.getElementById("logout-btn");
            signupbtn.innerHTML = "";
            loginbtn.innerHTML = "";
            myaccountbtn.style.display = "block";
             */
            /*          loginbtn.href = "logout";
             */         

        </script>
    </c:if>
     <c:if test="${temp1}">
                <script>
                    var loginbtn = document.getElementById("login-btn")
                    var signupbtn = document.getElementById("signup-btn")
                    var myaccountbtn = document.getElementById("logout-btn");

                    loginbtn.innerhtml  = "Login";
                    signupbtn.innerHTML = "Signup";
                    loginbtn.href = "login";
                    myaccountbtn.style.display = "none";

                </script>

        </c:if>
```

**Login.jsp**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="card card-container">
            <!-- <img class="profile-img-card" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="" /> -->
            <img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card"
                src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" />
            <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
            <form class="form-signin" action="validate">
                <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span> <input
                    type="username" name="username" id="inputEmail"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required> <input
                    type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
                    <label> <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                        Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin"
                    type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>
            <!-- /form -->
            <a href="#" class="forgot-password"> Forgot the password? </a>
        </div>
        <!-- /card-container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
</div>
```

**Header.jsp**

```
<li class="upper-links"><a class="links" id="signup-btn"
                    href="register">Signup</a></li>

                <li class="upper-links"><a class="links" id="login-btn"
                    href="login">Login</a></li>
                <li class="upper-links dropdown"><a
                    class="dropdown-toggle links" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="logout-btn"
                    href="loginHere"  style="display: none;">My Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 40%;">
                        <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wishlist</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="logout">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
```

Comment: You are using Spring Security, that already supports logout out-of-the-box... Why reinvent your own? Why work around the framework.

Comment: What I want to know is how do I get a login/logout button to display across the entire portal and our unauthenticated site based on if the user is logged in or out?  Is it possible for me to execute my code on the header somehow?  Or do you have any other suggestions? Currently when I click on signin button then value of temp is passed true and logout button is displayed but now when I click on any other page like about us value of temp hasn't been passed true ..so how to do this across complete portal?

Answer (score 1):

You can user  Http Session for track user and handle user login/ logout to your project, Base on session you can implement other business logic to your project.

Simple Login/ Logout In controller :

```
@PostMapping("/dologin")
public String userLogin(HttpSession session, @ModelAttribute("user") User 
user, Model model) {
    if (user.getEmail().equals("imranmadbar@gmail.com") && 
    user.getPassword().equals("12345")) {
        user.setFname("MD IMRAN");
        user.setMname("HOSSAIN");
        user.setLname("BABU");
        user.setAge(28);
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Login failed. Try again.");
        return "login";
    }
    return "redirect:/user/info";
}

@GetMapping("/logout")
public String logout(HttpSession session ) {
    session.invalidate();
    return "redirect:/login";
} 

@GetMapping("/info")
    public String userInfo(HttpSession session) {
    return "user";
}
```

After Login user and set user data on session scope you can access those data from any in the project.

Access data from user.jsp File:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored = "false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
       <title>BORAJI.COM</title>
    </head>
    <body>  

        <h4>User name: ${user.fname} ${user.mname} ${user.mname}</h4>
        <h4>User Age: ${user.age}</h4>
        <h4>User Email: ${user.email}</h4>
        <a href="/LoginRegUsingSession/logout">Log out</a><br>

    </body>
</html>
```

In my project i track user using spring interceptor.
You can check out my project use this link
https://github.com/imrangthub/LoginRegUsingSession/tree/master/LoginRegUsingSession